# jQuery draggable can still drop on empty - how do I stop it?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

If I have a jQuery Draggable object

```
$('#drag-me').draggable({
  helper: 'clone',
  connectToSortable: '#sortable'
});
```

and a connected sortable

```
$('#sortable').sortable({
  receive: performMagic
});
```

I can't prevent this draggable from dropping on the empty sortable.

Sortable *itself* has an option dropOnEmpty, which, when set to false, prevents you dropping things from *that* sortable onto an empty sortable; but Draggable doesn't have such an option.

I tried this:

```
$('#sortable').sortable({
  start: function(e, ui) {
    if (ui.item[0].nodeName == 'IMG') {
       $(this).sortable('cancel')
     }
  }
});
```

In my case the #drag-me element is an image but the Sortable elements are not. The performMagic function is successfully converting the image into the TBODY element that the sortable comprises. But results were inconsistent; sometimes it would successfully cancel the operation but other times it would break in other places.

The question is, am I on the right track? Is this the only way of preventing a Draggable from being dropped on an empty linked Sortable? Is there a way I can hijack the existing Sortable-to-Sortable behaviour?

TIA
Al

Answer (score 0):

Can you check whether the sortable is empty in the `receive` event? Something like:

```
$('#sortable').sortable({
  receive: function(event, ui) { 
    if ($('#sortable').children().length > 0) {
        // PerformMagic...
    }
  }
});
```